# SqlConnection State is always Closed at Execution

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to make a simple MS Access Database connection by using the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects.

As you can see here is how I make the connection:

```
private SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    String connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    return conn;
}
```

And before you ask, yes I have tried to move this piece of code to the method that calls it. Didn't change anything. It still reads the connection string wrong.

The connection string looks like this and is located in the `App.config` file:

```
<add name="ConnString" connectionString="Server=*.*.*.*;Database=familie;User Id=mfs;Password=********;"/>
```

But when I get this error:

[image: Error Image]

And look at the connection string object at the time, the string looks like this:

```
"data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

I have spent about 2 hours now trying to make this work, going to many different sites to figure out what I did wrong, but I either get information is that is too old, conflicting or deals with connecting to a local database, when this is in fact an external one access through a proxy that was given to me by my client (TrustGate if anyone should ask)

The method that calls `GetConnection()` looks like this:

```
public Dictionary<int,String> GetPostNrList()
{
    SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Execute dbo.HENT_POST_NR_LISTE", conn);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Dictionary<int, String> liste = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    while (reader.NextResult())
    {
        int post_nr = (int) reader.GetSqlInt32(0);
        String by = reader.GetString(1);
        liste.Add(post_nr, by);
    }
    CloseConnection(conn);
    return liste;
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is it located in the app.config file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception message tells you exactly what the problem is - your connection is not open. You just need to open the connection prior to executing a command:

```
conn.Open();
```

BTW, a good pattern is to using a `using` block when dealing with SQL connections, to ensure it gets disposed properly:

```
using (var conn = GetConnection())
{
    using (var comm = xxxxxxx)
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // xxxxx
        }
    }
}
```

You don't have to specifically close anything - the `using` pattern does all that for you.

Comment: I thought this was like Java, where it opened it itself...that is sort of retarded if you ask me. But I will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: Yep, I originally found it kind of strange that you have to specifically open the connection, but I guess it's so that you can control exactly how long to keep the connection open, since you should make it as short a time as possible.

Comment: @Vipar, a good finally block around SQL calls is finally{ if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();} but! sorry didn't see code block, he has it in using() so it will be disposed if you don't dispose of it then that finally block is good at the end.